# MasterDetailPage "Split" in UWP

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp

I'm using Xamarin.Forms (v. 3.4.0.1008975) to build a UWP app on Windows 10 (1809).

I would like to create a MasterDetailPage with split behavior (a fixed navigation menu that is always visible on the left and content pages displayed on the right). This is documented [here](https://blog.xamarin.com/implement-drawer-split-ui-xamarin-forms-masterdetailpage/).

Using the sample code available [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/Navigation/MasterDetailPage/), I've added the MasterBehavior="Split" to the XAML/MainPage.xaml file in the MasterDetailPageNavigation project:

```
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
              xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
              xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MasterDetailPageNavigation;assembly=MasterDetailPageNavigation"
              x:Class="MasterDetailPageNavigation.MainPage"
              MasterBehavior="Split">
```

I expect to see a fixed navigation menu on the left with a content page displayed on the right. However, the resulting UWP app continues to display "Popover" behavior (the menu slides in and out over the content page).

How do I get a MasterDetailPage with a fixed (not-moving) menu?

Comment: What version of XF are you using?

Comment: updated question with XF version 3.4.0.1008975

Comment: Your query is solved right?

Comment: Yes, solved. I overlooked the line in the code-behind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check `MainPage` code behind in your provided sample. The `MasterBehavior` was set in the `MainPage` constructor. And it will be invoked after **Xaml** initialized. So the `Split` behavior will be covered.

```
public partial class MainPage : MasterDetailPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        masterPage.listView.ItemSelected += OnItemSelected;

        if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.UWP)
        {
            MasterBehavior = MasterBehavior.Popover;
        }
    }

    void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = e.SelectedItem as MasterPageItem;
        if (item != null)
        {
            Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(item.TargetType));
            masterPage.listView.SelectedItem = null;
            IsPresented = false;
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to use `Split` behavior, you could modify the following line. And remove `MasterBehavior="Popover"` from xaml.

```
if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.UWP)
{
    MasterBehavior = MasterBehavior.Split;
}
```